# Rubymine and running rspec "rspec-core is not part of the bundle"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubymine

I am trying to run a rails app which was not created using rubymine. Its is a very different sort of app using rails engines loaded...When I try running tests, I get the following error message

```
Testing started at 12:29 ...
/Users/userbnamexxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:214:in `block in replace_gem': rspec-core is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/userbnamexxxx/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/bin/rspec:22:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I edited the configuration and it does have bundle exec checkbox checked. Tests tuns fine in the console. I tried it another project which is a default bug standard rails app and its fine there... I am using rbenv for managing ruby versions....
Please help as I am really stuck and it would be nice to not use the terminal....

Comment: ma getting same, I do have the gem inside Gemfile.lock
and still `bundle show rspec-score` wont show it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the gem

**rspec-core**

into your .Gemfile